# SELECT ROW based on MAX quantity and SUM quantity of grouped by fields

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I am trying to SUM the qty rows and group them by part number and bin then choose the bin that had the max quantity to begin with. In the query below it is only choosing bin 1-B. My result set should be for Part 1-2345: Bin 1-A, SUM qty of bins = 150 , total in that bin = 100

```
CREATE TABLE inventory (
ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
bin nvarchar(25),
partnumber nvarchar(25),
qty int
);

INSERT INTO inventory ( bin, partnumber, qty)
VALUES ('1-A', '1-2345', '100'), ('1-A', '1-2347', '10'), ('1-A', '1-2348', 
'15'), ('1-B', '1-2345', '50'), ('1-B', '1-2347', '50'), ('1-B', '1-2348', 
'55')

;With cte as
    ( SELECT bin, partnumber, sum(qty) qty
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER( Partition By  partnumber ORDER BY bin desc) as rn 
from inventory
     GROUP BY bin, partnumber) 
SELECT * FROM cte where rn = 1
```

Result set should be
Output:

```
bin partnumber  sum_of_bins max_qty_in_bin  
1-A 1-2345      150         100             
1-B 1-2347      60          50              
1-B 1-2348      70          55
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a whirl:

```
DECLARE @inventory TABLE (ID int IDENTITY(1,1), bin nvarchar(25), partnumber nvarchar(25), qty int);

INSERT INTO @inventory ( bin, partnumber, qty)
VALUES ('1-A', '1-2345', '100'), ('1-A', '1-2347', '10'), ('1-A', '1-2348','15'), ('1-B', '1-2345', '50'), ('1-B', '1-2347', '50'), ('1-B', '1-2348', '55')

;WITH CTE AS
    ( 
        SELECT bin, partnumber
                , sum(qty) OVER(Partition By partnumber) AS sum_of_bins
                , max(qty) OVER(Partition By partnumber) AS max_qty_in_bin
                , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By partnumber ORDER BY qty desc) as rn 
        FROM @inventory
        GROUP BY bin, partnumber, qty) 

SELECT * 
FROM cte
WHERE rn=1
```

Output:

```
bin partnumber  sum_of_bins max_qty_in_bin  rn
1-A 1-2345      150         100             1
1-B 1-2347      60          50              1
1-B 1-2348      70          55              1
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't give us sample output, it is not clear what you are trying to do. From your last sentence:

```
With cte as
( SELECT bin, partnumber, 
      sum(qty) over (Partition By  partnumber) as sumQty,
      sum(qty) over (Partition By  partnumber Order by bin) as totQty,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( Partition By  partnumber ORDER BY bin) as rn 
from inventory
) 
SELECT * FROM cte where rn = 1;
```

Here is [DBFiddle Demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3417800584e9bace14f9f324e5eb454d)

Comment: sample output is in the question.  My result set should be for Part 1-2345: Bin 1-A, SUM qty of bins = 150 , total in that bin = 100, thank you for the help!

Comment: Yes, I mean that explanation is not explanatory at all about what you want. The query I gave matches that explanation. IOW what does max sum qty mean?

Comment: gotcha. i see what you are saying now. clear in my head but not on question. I will save the result set above

Comment: @BrianMichaels,  OK I don't understand your requirement but you already marked an answer (what if more than one have the same value).